# Numpy where with indices along with values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy-ndarray

I have an array

```
import numpy as np
t = np.array([[1,2,3],
 [2,3,4],
 [5,6,7],
 [8,9,1]])
```

I need array indices where value is greater than 5 along with the actual values. Like below:

```
[[(2, 1),6], [(2, 2),7], [(3, 0),8], [(3, 1),9]]
```

I tried below:

```
result = np.where(t>5)
list(zip(result[0], result[1]))
```

This gives me only the indices

```
[(2, 1), (2, 2), (3, 0), (3, 1)]
```

Any pointer?

Comment: `[[idx, val] for idx, val in np.ndenumerate(t) if val > 5]` if your array size is relatively small.  Otherwise try something like `list(zip(*result, t[result]))`

Answer (score 0):

just incase its a pandas dataframe, since pandas is tagged, you can also try;

```
#df  = pd.DataFrame(t) 
[*df.where(df.gt(5)).stack().to_dict().items()]
```

---

Output:

```
[((2, 1), 6.0), ((2, 2), 7.0), ((3, 0), 8.0), ((3, 1), 9.0)]
```

Or;

```
[*map(list,df.where(df.gt(5)).stack().to_dict().items())]
```

---

Output:

```
[[(2, 1), 6.0], [(2, 2), 7.0], [(3, 0), 8.0], [(3, 1), 9.0]]
```